# When I download an ebook using Tor it does not go into Downloads directory. Why?

Tags: downloads, tor

I am brand new to Ubuntu and would love to use my Calibre e-reader, but whenever I download an e book from Tor it disappears, and cannot be found in download folder

Comment: As you download the eBooks?

Answer (score 1):

> When I download an ebook **using Tor** it does not go into my
>   downloads folder. Why?

Then you should search where your tor is downloading the files. Suppose for example you are using `transmission`. when you open a new torrent then you can specify where to save(download).

[image]

So What you have to do is to check place to download from your tor client.

Answer (score 1):

it downloads things to a data folder for the Tor Browser which is kept separate from your regular downloads folder... I'm guessing for security reasons.

If you know the file name you can find it like so:

```
find ~ |grep filename.ext
```

For me that revealed this folder:

```
cd ~/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/Downloads/
```

That was on Xenial with the bundled torbrowser-launcher package.

Comment: Or you could `find . -type f -iname 'filename*'` or even `locate filename.ext` the day after the download.